# Script section works only in one view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a huge project in C# MVC. In one of the views, in index.cshtml, I have a code like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Library.Models.Customer>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Customers";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Klienci</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Nowy klient", "New", "Customers", null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary" })
</p>

<table id ="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Klient</th>
        <th>Typ Czlonkostwa</th>
        <th>Usun</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var table = $("#customers").DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: "/api/customers",
                    dataSrc: ""
                },
                columns: [
                    {
                        data: "Name",
                        render: function(data, type, customer) {
                            return "<a href='/customers/edit/" + customer.Id + "'>" + customer.Name + "</a>";
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        data: "MembershipType.Name"
                    },
                    {
                        data: "Id",
                        render: function(data) {
                            return "<button class='btn-link js-delete' data-customer-id=" + data + ">Delete</button>";
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });

            $("#customers").on("click", ".js-delete",
                function () {
                    var button = $(this);

                    if (confirm("Na pewno chcesz usunac?")) {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: "/api/customers/" + button.attr("data-customer-id"),
                            method: "DELETE",
                            success: function () {
                                //datatable methods - row, remove and draw
                                table.row(button.parents("tr")).remove().draw();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

It works like a charm. But in another view, I have the code like this:

```
<table id="customers" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Ksiazka</th>
    <th>Gatunek</th>
    <th>Delete</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var book in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.ActionLink(book.Name, "Edit", "Books", new { id = book.Id }, null)</td>
        <td>@book.Genre.Name</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn-link" js-delete>Delete</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
```

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#customers .js-delete").on("click",
                function() {
                    confirm("Sure?");
                });
        });
    </script>
}
```

and it doesn't work. I mean, it compiles without any errors or warnings, but when I click Delete button nothing happens (should pop up confirm box).

What am I doing wrong?

If needed, I can provide whole code from these both views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.js-delete` means that "js-delete" is assumed to be a css class, while in the html it is an attribute. To search for elements with a particular attribute, you need ["has attribute"](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) selector:

```
$("#customers [js-delete]")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works now! If you can tell me, why in the first view I didn't have to use "has attribute"? (I can mark your answer in 5 minutes)

Comment: I would assume because in your first view (which you did not show), "js-delete" is actually a class. Perhaps you just mistyped it in the second view, and that was supposed to be `<button class="btn-link js-delete"`>?

Comment: I am new to the javascript, but I assume I don't have a "js-delete" class in my first view (I've jsut edited first post whit whole first view).

Comment: @Lucas, in your first view in the js code you have `class='btn-link js-delete'`, which makes js-delete as css class

Comment: can you help me with one more thing? If yes, I will post a new question.

Comment: @Lucas, you can absolutely post a new question, happy to help out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171703/discussion-between-lucas-and-andrei).